# Projection map help please

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Problem:
Let $V$ be finite dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ be normal. Show that there are subspace $U_1,U_2,...,U_k$ such that $T$ is a linear combination of projection maps onto $U_i$. Also give a counter-example to show the converse is not true.

Background:
$T$ is normal if $TT^*=T^*T$ where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Work:
I know it has to do with $\lambda_1,.....\lambda_k$ being eigenvalues and $U_i =\{v \in V : Tv =\lambda_i v\}$ but I don't really know what it means by linear combination of projection maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is normal, $T$ is diagonalisable and V has a  basis of eigenvectors of T. Let $\lambda_i, i=1,..,n$ be the eigenvalues (with multiplicity) and $v_i$ be the corresponding eigenvectors which form a basis. Then consider the projection map $\pi_i$ from $V$ onto $Null(T-\lambda_i I)$ and verify that $T=\sum_{i=1} ^n \pi_i$

Comment: oh okay i see. How do you do the counter example though??

Comment: What do you want as a counter example ? I mean I didn't get that part of the question.

Comment: I think it means show that a linear combination of projection maps need not be normal